# Error System.StackOverflowException

Tags: c#

He estado haciendo este codigo para hacer un laberinto y resolverlo.
Lo primero crea un vector de paneles y labels, los paneles son las casillas del tablero, y el texto de los labels dice si es un muro(#), camino libre(+), camino ya cruzado(-), el inicio(/), o el final o la salida(*).

```
    void generaTableroLaberinto()
    {
        /*Genera la cuadricula completa del laberinto, con un label con un # lo que significa que ese panel es un muro*/
        tablero = new Panel[tamañoLaberinto * tamañoLaberinto];
        indice = new Label[tamañoLaberinto * tamañoLaberinto];
        int a;

        for (int i = 0; i < tamañoLaberinto*tamañoLaberinto; i++)
        {
            a = azar.Next(1, 5);
            tablero[i] = new Panel();
            tablero[i].BackColor = Color.Beige;
            tablero[i].Width = 40;
            tablero[i].Height = 40;
            tablero[i].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;

            //----------------------------------------------------

            indice[i] = new Label();

            /*Le da valores de # y + al laberinto al azar*/
            if (a == 1)
            {
                indice[i].Text = "#";
            }
            else
            {
                indice[i].Text = "+";
            }

            // indice[i].Text = (i).ToString();
            indice[i].Visible = true;
            indice[i].AutoSize = true;

            //----------------------------------------------------
            indice[i].Show();
            tablero[i].Show();
            tablero[i].Controls.Add(indice[i]);

            //Muestra el vector en forma de tablero----------------------------------------------------

            if (i == 0)
            {
                tablero[i].Location = new Point(20, 20);
                tablero[i].BackColor = Color.Orange;
                indice[i].Text = "/";
            }
            else
            {
                if(i % tamañoLaberinto == 0)
                {
                    tablero[i].Location = new Point(tablero[i-tamañoLaberinto].Location.X, tablero[i-tamañoLaberinto].Location.Y + 40);
                }
                else
                {
                    tablero[i].Location = new Point(tablero[i-1].Location.X + 40, tablero[i-1].Location.Y);
                }

            }
            if(i == (tamañoLaberinto*tamañoLaberinto) - 1)
            {
                tablero[i].BackColor = Color.Green;
                indice[i].Text = "*";
            }
            panel1.Controls.Add(tablero[i]);

        }

    }
```

Y este lo recorre hasta llegar hasta el final, los paneles recorridos se ponen en rojo, pero al ejecutar esta parte aparece el error "System.StackOverflowException" en el primer if, y no sé porqué

```
    void solucionLaberinto(int x1)
    { Boolean termina = false;
        int x2, k;
        k = 0;
        int[] mov = new int[5];
        mov[1] = 1;
        mov[2] = -1;
        mov[3] = tamañoLaberinto;
        mov[4] = -tamañoLaberinto;
        //-------------------------
        do
        {
            k = k + 1;
            x2 = x1 + mov[k];
            if (indice[x2].Text.Equals("+"))
            {
                //tablero[x2][y2] = s;
                tablero[x2].BackColor = Color.Red;
                if (indice[x2].Text != "*")
                {
                    solucionLaberinto(x2);
                    if (!termina)
                    {
                        indice[x2].Text = "-";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    termina = true;
                }
            }


        } while (k < 4 && !termina);

    }
```

Comment: Si tienes un método recursivo y ves `StackOverflowException`, el problema es que el método se está invocando a sí mismo infinidad de veces sin parar.  Tienes que revisar bien las condiciones del algoritmo, recórrelo paso a paso, iteración por iteración y descubrirás el error.

Comment: Es importante cuando se hace una llamada recursiva que esa llamada termine algun momento, sino se te mete en un bucle infinito.

Answer (score 0):

Tu código se parece mucho a una práctica de backtracking que hice en la carrera. Supongo que van por ahí los tiros así que te comento donde creo que está el fallo.

El problema creo que está en que no tienes ninguna condición que evalue si ya ha pasado por una casilla. De esta forma el programa se queda en bucle pasando siempre por los mismos (en circulos) hasta que da un error de StackOverflow.
Si trazas el código debería darte que la primera ejecución se mueve hacia x1+1 y así hasta llegar al ancho del tablero. Luego explora x1-1 con lo cual vuelve a explorar el camino a la izquierda por donde ha venido, lo cual es incorrecto.

La solución sería pasar en un parámetro de la función recursiva una copia del tablero. Digo esto porque la función recursiva también debería devolver true o false si ha alcanzado la meta o si ese camino está cortado.
Solo si devuelve true, puedes poner de color rojo el camino por el que ha pasado en el tablero original (solución correcta). Si lo haces directamente sobre el tablero original, una ejecución de un camino afectará a la ejecución de otro y no funcionará.

La idea base del backtracking es que una llamada recursiva explore un camino en profundidad y, si es el correcto indicarlo. Pero si no es el correcto, se va deshaciendo hasta un paso anterior donde quede un camino sin explorar. Y para eso precisamente usamos las variables temporales que nos da la pila.

La pila también tiene un tamaño limitado asi que tamaños medianos de tablero te darán un StackOverflow aunque el código esté correcto. Por eso, si estas usando esto para inteligencia artifical, es mejor usar algoritmos de búsqueda más modernos.

Espero haberte servido de ayuda y te pido disculpas por adelantado si mi respuesta no es adecuada.